# how to add mean to a beeswarm plot

Tags: r

Here is the data set (d2):

```
    WT.hypo  WT.hyper   KO.hypo KO.hyper
1 11.996507  2.406066 10.903488 7.595285
2 10.992267  2.192558  9.399490 7.184496
3 16.797177 11.088748  6.221103 4.293984
4  9.918818  2.937259  6.317434 3.319860
5        NA        NA  5.918438 2.914264
```

Here is the script:

```
#beeswarm
beeswarm(d2, method="swarm", col = c("black"), pch = 16, cex.axis = 1, cex = 1 ) 

#add mean
m <- mean(d2, na.rm=T)
segments(0.9,m[[1]],1.1,m[[1]], lwd = 2, lty = 3, col = "black")
```

Seems like some arguments are missing in "m<- mean(d2, na.rm=T)"

Dataset:

```
d2=structure(list(WT.hypo = c(11.996507, 10.992267, 16.797177, 9.918818, 
NA), WT.hyper = c(2.406066, 2.192558, 11.088748, 2.937259, NA
), KO.hypo = c(10.903488, 9.39949, 6.221103, 6.317434, 5.918438
), KO.hyper = c(7.595285, 7.184496, 4.293984, 3.31986, 2.914264
)), .Names = c("WT.hypo", "WT.hyper", "KO.hypo", "KO.hyper"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use `dput(d2)` to show your data.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make a vector of means:

```
> means=apply(d2, 2, function(x) mean(na.omit(x))) #don't forget na.omit
> means
  WT.hypo  WT.hyper   KO.hypo  KO.hyper 
12.426192  4.656158  7.751991  5.061578
```

Then you can add the lines:

```
> segments(0.9, means[[1]], 1.1, means[[1]], lwd=2, lty=3, col="black")
> segments(1.9, means[[2]], 2.1, means[[2]], lwd=2, lty=3, col="black")
> segments(2.9, means[[3]], 3.1, means[[3]], lwd=2, lty=3, col="black")
> segments(3.9, means[[4]], 4.1, means[[4]], lwd=2, lty=3, col="black")
```

[image]

I'd advise you to think about using the built-in `bxplot()` function that comes in `beeswarm` though; it's much easier.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

as @Matt said, you can do like this:

```
beeswarm(d2, method="swarm", col = c("black"), pch = 16, cex.axis = 1, cex = 1 ) 
bxplot(d2, add = TRUE, probs = 0.5)
```

and my question is how to draw a picture like this, the 3 lines are not the same length.

[image]